# Implementation approaches of event sourcing with microservices

Tags: java, event-sourcing

I'm currently wrapping my head around event sourcing and microservices, and so far, I can image the following approaches. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm also looking for other possible approaches.

**Approach 1:**

Each microservice is connected to a central Event Store. A *Microservice A* can publish events to the Event Store, *other Microservcies* subscribe to these events.

**Approach 2:**

Each microservice has local event store. A *microservice A* can directly send an event via a message broker to another *microservice B*.

**Approach 3:**

Each microservice has local event store. A *microservice A* can subscribe to an event store of another *microservice B*.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the first option. When dealing with any cross cutting concerns you might find it easier to have all your domain events in one place.

We're currently running in production an architecture based on approach 1 with roughly 20 services so far.